# Child object not instantiating on parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of position in Unity.

Have a parent object (Player). On that player, I have a child object called "Gun". On the gun, I have a script to fire bullets. When I fire the bullets, it spawns to the left of the gun, and the player.

I've tried offsetting the bullet's position on spawn, but when I turn around, the location is incorrect (it's still not centered on the gun). I also have a feeling that the offset that I've tried is a hack, and that I've missed something somewhere.

My code for the firing script on the gun :

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1") > 0)
    {
        var pos = transform.position;
        print(pos.ToString());
        var proj = Instantiate(projectile, pos, Quaternion.identity);

        proj.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;

    }
}
```

The only other thing touching the bullet, is my BulletController, a script on the bullet :

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    //rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);
    rb.velocity = transform.up * 10;

}
```

Attached screenshot of my setup 
[image]

Comment: Can you print out the position of the bullet on the frame after it is spawned and also when the movement is updated? It's possible that the first frame of movement is offsetting, or that your bullet prefab is not set to 0, 0, 0

Comment: @Eliasar Unsure what you mean with "on the frame after it is spawned", but what I've done is added a script on the bullet, that prints out its position on Update, and that is 0,0,0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to position the bullet to a relative offset based on the facing of the gun, right? If you set the position as you do now, you do it in world position unrelated to the facing of the gun.

Now, there are 2 ways how you can do it:

Place the bullet as a child object of the gun with a relative *local* position and unparent it immediately. Not a nice solution and resembles more a hack.

Or use the following methods, which I created:

```
/// <summary> Returns a vector which is relative to the facing and position of 'c'. </summary>
public static Vector3 RelativePosition (Transform c, Vector3 target)
{
    return c.right * target.x + c.up * target.y + c.forward * target.z + c.position;
}

/// <summary> Returns a vector which is relative. </summary>
public static Vector3 RelativePosition (Vector3 position, Vector3 forward, Vector3 up, Vector3 right, Vector3 target)
{
    return right * target.x + up * target.y + forward * target.z + position;
}
```

And complementary this:

```
/// <summary> Returns a vector which is relative to the facing of 'c'. </summary>
public static Vector3 RelativePositionZero (Transform c, Vector3 target)
{
    return c.right * target.x + c.up * target.y + c.forward * target.z;
}

/// <summary> Returns a vector which is relative. </summary>
public static Vector3 RelativePositionZero (Vector3 forward, Vector3 up, Vector3 right, Vector3 target)
{
    return right * target.x + up * target.y + forward * target.z;
}
```

Usage: Use the RelativePosition method, provide the Transform of the gun as parameter and the relative offset for the Vector3 parameter. Example:

```
        item.position = RelativePosition (Camera.Main.transform, new Vector3 (1.5f, 0f, 4.0f));
```

This would place the position of 'item' 4 unity distance in front of the camera and 1.5 unity distance to the right.

Hint: RelativePosition will give you the resulting world position as it is. This is what you use to receive the relative position you seek as world position. RelativePositionZero will give you the relative offset from the Transform object to the given Vector3 position. That can be used to determine if something is left or right, above or below, in front or behind the given Transform.

Comment: Ok, I think this is putting me on the right track. I've blindly copy&pasted your code now, without understanding it, and it's spawning the bullet in the right position, but it's bugging out when I turn around. I think this will help me, going to go through what you said, and your code now, to get a better grasp on it. Thanks so far. Will come back and report/accept when I have more understanding.

Comment: This seems like a lot of overkill for what I suggested already ^^ ... You know btw that you simply use `Vector3.Scale` instead of multiplying the components one by one? Don't reinvent the wheel ;)

Comment: @WynDiesel 'but it's bugging out when I turn around' This sounds like your bullet is a child object of the gun which you are rotating (they shouldn't be parented). My advice is that you create an empty GameObject in your scene, which contains ALL objects which are supposed to have no parent (like your bullets). When you instantiate objects, add them to that empty GameObject. It makes your scene more clean and should solve your problem.

Comment: @derHugo - Scaling doesn't work. Look more closely - It multiplies vectors from facing and floats. There is no global "Facing Vector" you could use. You can't just scale two vectors - it consists of 3 vectors (up, right, front). If you have only 1, you still don't know the other 2. The method bodies were originally quite some lines long until I got to the concise one-line solutions.

Comment: Yeah you're right didn't note that .. however you should simply use `transform.Translate` in local space (default) which does exactly the same

Comment: @derHugo - Good point. But 'transform.Translate' performs the movement and doesn't return a resulting Vector3, which you could further use or calculate with (which I do for example).

Comment: Yeah but OP just wants to set a position here ;) for other use cases this is surely useful but I think it confuses a bit in this case .. how do you decide whether you want to use the local axis of the "parent" or the "child" object?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Battle. Even though your answer and comment did learn me  more,and gave me insight into Unity's vectors, it didn't lead me to the answer. The problem was something much, much easier. It appears that my sprite's location wasn't zero'd out, and was off, which is why it kept on drawing in the wrong location all the time

Answer (score 1):

> feeling that the offset that I've tried is a hack

I don't see any offset .. you could do e.g.

```
public float offset = 0.5f;


if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Fire1") > 0)
{
    // add the offset here
    var pos = transform.position + transform.up * offset;
    print(pos.ToString());

    var proj = Instantiate(projectile, pos, Quaternion.identity);

    proj.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
}
```

`transform.position` spawns the bullet at the same place as the gun. I added `transform.up` since it seems this is the direction your player is looking to (in 3D space it would e.g. be `transform.forward` but in 2D it is either `transform.up` or `transform.right` depending in which direction the player looks by default). `offset` is just how far you want the bullet be placed in the given direction in meters/units.

---

If you rather want a `Vector3` offset for more control/for debugging which axis is the correct one you could instead use

```
public Vector3 offset;

//...

var proj = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

proj.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;

// Now move it to the offset in local space
proj.transform.Translate(offset, Space.Self);
```

---

You **don't** want to spawn it as child ... because if you than move or rotate after, your bullets will all also move and rotate together with you!

Comment: Could you perhaps explain the transform.up part to me?

Comment: As for your edit on adding it as a child. 100% correct. I see my bullets now magically turning in the air.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and explanation on transform.up, that makes sense. I've changed it to your suggestion, but still having the same effect, ie, the bullet spawning to the left of the player, at 0,0,0

Comment: hm are you sure there is not the pivot point of the gun? Is there nothing else manipulating the position of the gun and bullet?

Comment: Ive edited the post with the code on the bullet itself. Nothing else is touching the bullet

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I instantiated the sprite on the bullets on an offset, and not 0,0,0 relative to the actual gameobject.